# Can't Use Newly Created User to Run Postgres createdb Command

Tags: linux, postgresql

**Short Version:**

I get:

> error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"

when I try to `createdb --username admin --password mynewdb` ... but I created the "admin" user in both Linux and PostgreSQL, so I don't understand why I can't use them.

**Long Version:**

I am trying to create an "admin" user to run SQL on a brand new Ubuntu/AWS machine.  I created the user with

```
$ sudo useradd -g admin admin
```

Then I set their password using:

```
$ sudo passwd admin
```

I know the password was set correctly, because I can switch to the "admin" user by typing that password in, with:

```
$ su - admin
```

I also created a database role for the user, with:

```
CREATE ROLE admin WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'samepassword';
```

and I can see that the user was created with `\du` (from inside `psql`):

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

Furthermore, I can confirm, from my `pg_hba.conf` file, that Postgres should use the "peer" (ie. system) password for that user:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

And I restarted Postgres, just to be safe:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

However, despite all of the above, when I try to create a new database with that "admin" user, using `createdb`, I get prompted for my password, twice, and then it fails:

```
$ createdb --username admin --password mynewdb
Password: 
Password: 
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed:
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"
```

I've tried reading other SO answers for this error, but they all suggest things I've tried (ie. changing `pg_hba.conf`, restarting Postgres, etc.)  But, I'm sort of a Postgres newb, so if anyone has any further suggestions I would love to hear them.

Comment: There's a raft of possible causes for the error you're seing above ... do any of the answers/suggestions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/how-do-i-access-postgres-when-i-get-an-error-about-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form of peer authentication means the OS user can log into PostgreSQL as the PostgreSQL user which is spelled the same.  You didn't indicate who you ran createdb as, but I would guess it wasn't as the OS user 'admin', even though you did appear to create that user (you said you can switch to it, but not that you did switch to it for the rest of the question).

If you want to use password based authentication, you need to change pg_hba to do so.  If you want to use peer authentication, you need to *use* the OS user you created for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  So, if I wanted to be on Linux user A, but run `createdb` (or any DB command) as user B, in my pg_hba I'd want `md5` instead of `peer`?